# how to show partial view on mouse over on text in MVC3?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, partial-views

I'm developing web site using MVC3. I created a partial view which contains 4 images placed horizontally. Now i have another view that is detail view and i displayed one text. When user mouse over on that text i want to show my partial view of an image.

How to do this ?

Sorry that i'm including another question in same question because i think it is relevant to above question. So my next issue is -

when that images shown to the user then user select one of image from that list and depending on this i have to perform some operation.

I worked on given answer but i come to know that i can't perform other operation like selection on shown image list.

How to do this too ?

Answer (score 3):

Use `jQuery` to get the contents of the partial view and display them on `moveover` or a `hover`:

For example:

```
$("#container").mouseover(function() {
   $.ajax({
    url: "@Url.Action("YourPartialView")",
    type: "GET",
    success: function(data) {
        var htmlx = data; // the View

        $("#content").append(htmlx);
        $("#content").slideDown('slow');
        }
    }); 
});
```

Where `#container` is the area holding your text and `#content` is the area that will be displayed when the user hovers over the container.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to load the partial view dynamically on hover, you can do it using jquery ajax call:

```
$("img.your-class").mouseover(function () {

   // get the image ID - modify according to your markup
   var imageId = $(this).data('image-id');

   $.ajax({

       // use the imageId from above here
       url: "add-your-view-url", 

       success: function(data) {
          $("#target-div-id").html(data);
       }

    }); 

});
```

In your controller you will need to have action similar to this:

```
public ActionResult Action(int imageId)
{
     // get the model for your partial view
     var model = GetModel(imageId);

     // you can optionally return different result based on request type
     if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
     {
          // update with actual path of your partial view
          return PartialView("path-to-your-view", model);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do this using JavaScript, probably easier using jQuery ( a javascript library ).

You will need to have your Partial View wrapped in a hidden element, and then show this element when a user hovers over.

See http://api.jquery.com/hover/ for some more information and examples.

Also see here for a basic example: http://jsfiddle.net/49bAz/

Comment: Is it possible that only when user mouse over text then only load partial view ?

Comment: There is a difference between loading new content and showing hidden content that is already present in the page. What do you actually want?

Comment: Of course it is possible to do this, however I would only do this if the you are going to be dynamically changing these images based on a client side event which would stop you from just loading these images when rendering the page.

Answer (score 0):

try with jquery

```
$("#id").mouseover(function () {
   $.ajax({
       url: 'url',
       success: function (response) {
        $(response.responseText).appendTo($('body'));
    }
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also decide to call the action on mouse hover using ajax (with a parameter that identifies the image). Ajax call will return partial view and then you can wrap it in a div and present the way you want, e.g. using some tooltip library